# Two CryptoStreams associated with one file in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, filestream, cryptostream

I would like to create a file "myFile" that encrypts the first part using a certain key, and the last part using a certain key.  So far I have something like this:

```
cs1 = new CryptoStream(myFile, symmetricKey1.CreateEncryptor(key1, key1IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

cs2 = new CryptoStream(myFile, symmetricKey2.CreateEncryptor(key2, key2IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

And I would like to write to the first part of the file using cs1 and second with cs2 sort of like this:

```
while((data = fs1.readByte()) != -1){
    cs1.WriteByte(data);
}

while((data = fs2.readByte()) != -1){
    cs2.WriteByte(data);
}
```

This proceeds without error, but the second CryptoStream (cs2) does not actually write to the file.  Does anyone know why this would happen? Is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks

edit: Closing the CryptoStream does seem to close myFile as well, but if I close and then reopen and then start the second CryptoStream, this seems to work though its not as clean as I had hoped for.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should at least call cs1.FlushFinalBlock() after the while loop (same for cs2).

And create cs2 *after* you are done with cs1. You may have to investigate if closing cs1 close the myFile stream, StreamReaders will do that but i saw no mention of it in the CryptoStream documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following after each while loop.

```
csX.Flush();
csX.Dispose();
```

Or even better, use a using block and create cs2 after cs1 has already been disposed.